# XPath to select multiple child values

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, dom4j

How can i select **all/multiple** the values which satify below condition

**XPATH**

```
/X/X1/X2[@code='b']/X3/value
```

**XML:**

```
<X>
    <X1>
        <X2 code="a">
            <X3>
                <value>x3a1</value>
            </X3>
        </X2>
    </X1>
    <X1>
        <X2 code="b">
            <X3>
                <value>x3b11</value>
            </X3>
        </X2>
    </X1>
    <X1>
        <X2 code="b">
            <X3>
                <value>X3b12</value>
            </X3>
        </X2>
    </X1>

</X>
```

**Code:**

```
import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.Node;
Document doc = reader.read(new StringReader(xml));
Node valueNode = doc.selectSingleNode(XPATH);
```

**Expected value**

```
x3b11, X3b12
```

Comment: Then use `Document.selectNodes()` rather than `Document.selectSingleNode()`

Comment: thank you, let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`Document.selectSingleNode()`](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.3/org/dom4j/Node.html#selectSingleNode-java.lang.String-), use [`Document.selectNodes()`](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.3/org/dom4j/Node.html#selectNodes-java.lang.String-) to select multiple nodes.

Also consider [`XPath.selectNodes()`](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.1.3/org/dom4j/XPath.html#selectNodes-java.lang.Object-); here is a full [example](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/wiki/Cookbook#using-xpath) from the [DOM4J Cookbook](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/wiki/Cookbook):

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.dom4j.Documet;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.XPath;

public class DeployFileLoaderSample {

  private org.dom4j.Document doc;
  private org.dom4j.Element root;

  public void browseRootChildren() {

    /* 
      Let's look how many "James" are in our XML Document an iterate them  
      ( Yes, there are three James in this project ;) )
    */
      
    XPath xpathSelector = DocumentHelper.createXPath("/people/person[@name='James']");
    List results = xpathSelector.selectNodes(doc);
    for ( Iterator iter = results.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
      Element element = (Element) iter.next();
      System.out.println(element.getName());
    }

    // select all children of address element having person element with attribute and value "Toby" as parent
    String address = doc.valueOf( "//person[@name='Toby']/address" );

    // Bob's hobby
    String hobby = doc.valueOf( "//person[@name='Bob']/hobby/@name" );

    // the second person living in UK
    String name = doc.value( "/people[@country='UK']/person[2]" );
    
    // select people elements which have location attriute with the value "London"
    Number count = doc.numberValueOf( "//people[@location='London']" );
  }
}
```